# why list of id not sent by jQuery to razor page although it display on console log correctly?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I work on asp.net razor page . i face issue when sent list of id from jQuery ajax to razor

page it display on razor page as count 0 although it display on console of browser two items

on array

```
public JsonResult OnGetListIdUpdated(List<int> selectedIds)
        {
            return new JsonResult(selectedIds);
        }


$(document).ready(function () {

            $('#reprintdatabtn').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                  var selectedIds = [];
    $("input[name='chkSel']:checked").each(function() {
                    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:last").text();
      if (id !== "") {
        selectedIds.push(parseInt(id));
      }
                }); 
                console.log(selectedIds);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=ListIdUpdated',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { selectedIds: selectedIds },


                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#lblRowsCount").html(response.counter);
                        $('#msgstatus').text(response.messageStatus);
                        // Handle the server response here
                    }
                });
            });
});
```

so on browser `console.log(selectedIds);` i get data correctly as below

```
[
    16810,
    16811
]
```

and when debug this line below on razor it display null

```
public JsonResult OnGetListIdUpdated(List<int> selectedIds)
```

so why this issue happen please

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the `POST` method is more suitable for you. Don't forget to add `RequestVerificationToken` header when sending `POST` request.

Below is a working demo, you can refer to it:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.IAntiforgery Xsrf
@functions {
    public string GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()
    {
        return Xsrf.GetAndStoreTokens(Model.HttpContext).RequestToken;
    }
}

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Check</td>
            <td>Id</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name='chkSel' /></td>
            <td>16810</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name='chkSel' /></td>
            <td>16811</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name='chkSel' /></td>
            <td>16812</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<div>
    <button id="reprintdatabtn">Click</button>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#reprintdatabtn').click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var selectedIds = [];
                $("input[name='chkSel']:checked").each(function () {
                    var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:last").text();
                    if (id !== "") {
                        selectedIds.push(parseInt(id));
                    }
                });
                console.log(selectedIds);
                $.ajax({
                    url: '?handler=ListIdUpdated',
                    type: "POST",
                    headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": '@GetAntiXsrfRequestToken()' },
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { selectedIds: selectedIds },
                    success: function (response) {
                        //$("#lblRowsCount").html(response.counter);
                        //$('#msgstatus').text(response.messageStatus);
                        // Handle the server response here
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

PageModel:

```
public JsonResult OnPostListIdUpdated([FromForm] List<int> selectedIds)
{
    return new JsonResult(selectedIds);
}
```

Test Result:

[image]

If you must use `HttpGet`, then you need to send a request like this: `?handler=ListIdUpdated&selectedIds=16810&selectedIds=16811`, and receive parameters from `Query`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#reprintdatabtn').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var selectedIds = [];
            $("input[name='chkSel']:checked").each(function () {
                var id = $(this).closest("tr").find("td:last").text();
                if (id !== "") {
                    selectedIds.push(parseInt(id));
                }
            });
            console.log(selectedIds);
            var url = '?handler=ListIdUpdated';
            for(var i=0;i<selectedIds.length;i++)
            {
                url = url + '&selectedIds=' + selectedIds[i]
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    //$("#lblRowsCount").html(response.counter);
                    //$('#msgstatus').text(response.messageStatus);
                    // Handle the server response here
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PageModel:

```
public JsonResult OnGetListIdUpdated([FromQuery] List<int> selectedIds)
{
    return new JsonResult(selectedIds);
}
```

Test Result:

[image]